# Not able to link dropbox using DropBoxSDK.framework, if Dropbox Application is installed in Device

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox-api

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
```

or

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

none of these 2 methods of AppDelegate is getting called(If I have dropbox app installed in my device) when I request to link dropbox using

```
[[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:rootViewController];
```

giving error like

```
 'The signature method "(null)" is not currently support by MPOAuthConnection'
```

but if I delete dropbox application from my device, it is working almost fine. 
I am using DropBoxSDK.framework. I have set urlSchema as per given example in SDK.

Comment: Now it is getting called and working fine..as I have change restclient declaration logic.

cause somehow it was getting null for rest client, so I changed that each time restclient create an object after nullifying old one.
and also passed self.rootViewCintroller instead of only rootViewController while linking to dropbox.

Comment: getting same issue, but randomly not always. what should i do to fix, can you guide me?